# tkinterでスクロールバー(Scrollbar)の有効範囲を広げたい

Tags: python, tkinter

#### 前提

TkinterでCanvasとScrollbarを使用してCheckbutton入りのリストボックスを作成しています。

#### 実現したいこと

Scrollbarのスクロール有効範囲を広げたいです。
現状はスクロールバー上にカーソルがある場合のみスクロールが効きます。
CanvasやCheckbutton上にカーソルがあってもスクロールが効くようにしたいです。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ItemListFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=100, height=100,
                          borderwidth=1, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        
        #ウィジェット配置
        self.place_widget()
        
    def place_widget(self):
        
        #Canvas作成
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master=self, width=300, height=200, bg='white')
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        #スクロールバー
        vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self, orient=tk.VERTICAL) #縦方向
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
        
        #スクロールバーの制御をCanvasに通知する処理
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        
        #Canvasの可動域をスクロールバーに通知する処理
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        
        #スクロール可動域
        canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0, 300, 5000))
        
        #Frameを作成しcanvasに配置
        frame = tk.Frame(master=canvas, bg='white')
        canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW, width=canvas.cget('width'))
        
        self.vars = []
        for i in range(50):
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            self.vars.append(var)
            check_button = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text=i, variable=var)
            check_button.grid(row=i, column=0)
            
root = tk.Tk()
frame = ItemListFrame(root)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python3.10
Windows 10
VScode

Comment: 「スクロールが効く」ではなく、「マウスホイールでスクロールできる」が正しいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: もう一つ質問です。サンプルコードでは、CanvasがmasterでFrameが作られ、そのFrame上にチェックボタンが並んでいます。本当は、Frameの内部に、チェックボタンとCanvasを配置し、スクロールがしたいのではないでしょうか？現在は、チェックボタンが並んだFrameが上部にあり、その下にCanvasが配置されています。Canvasに同期されたスクロールバーが右端にありますが、Frameとの連動制は取れていません。

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi 
表現があいまいでした。正しくは「マウスホイールでスクロールできる」です。
また、Canvas上にFrameを作ることで間違いありません。

Answer (score 0):

ソースコードが意図通りだという前提で、マウスホイールスクロールを対応すると、以下のようになります。

このケースの場合、canvas,frame,各チェックボタンに""イベントをバインドして、スクロール移動量に反映します。

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ItemListFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=100, height=100,
                          borderwidth=1, relief=tk.GROOVE)

        # ウィジェット配置
        self.place_widget()

    def place_widget(self):
        inframe = tk.Frame(master=self, bg='white')
        inframe.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Canvas作成
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master=inframe, width=300, height=200, bg='white')
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # スクロールバー
        vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(master=inframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL)  # 縦方向
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        # スクロールバーの制御をCanvasに通知する処理
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        # Canvasの可動域をスクロールバーに通知する処理
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

        # スクロール可動域
        canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 300, 5000))

        # Frameを作成しcanvasに配置
        frame = tk.Frame(master=canvas, bg='white')
        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame,
                             anchor=tk.NW, width=canvas.cget('width'))
        frame.bind("<MouseWheel>",
                   lambda event: self._mousewheel_(event, canvas))
        canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",
                    lambda event: self._mousewheel_(event, canvas))

        self.vars = []
        for i in range(50):
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            self.vars.append(var)
            check_button = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text=i, variable=var)
            check_button.grid(row=i, column=0)
            check_button.bind("<MouseWheel>",
                              lambda event: self._mousewheel_(event, canvas))

    def _mousewheel_(self, event, canvas):
        canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
        print(event)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = ItemListFrame(root)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事上記のコードで解決しました。
Frameとの連動の仕方が分からなくて困っていましたがイベントをバインドしてやるんですね。
お陰様で次に進めそうです。